# Why can't we extend a generic type?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

We have the following code:

```
class MyClass<T>{
...
}
class MyExtendedClass extends MyClass<T>{//Compile error
...
}
```

I've tried to create non generic class which is a subtype of the generic class. Why is it forbidden?

Comment: `T` doesn't refer to anything there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should either put in a concrete class there:

```
class MyExtendedClass extends MyClass<String>
```

Or add a generic class to your subclass

```
class MyExtendedClass<T> extends MyClass<T>
```

The way you use it now, what would you expect to be the type of `T` when you declare an instance of `MyExtendedClass` as follows:

```
MyExtendedClass x = new MyExtendedClass();
```

There is no way to tell what `T` should be in that case!

Comment: I understand this, but what occur if we'll permit that non generic type may be a subtype of generic type?

Comment: @St.Antario that is permitted, you just have to fill in some actual types for the generic type parameters.